# Performing a dry run of a Powershell script that uses Chocolatey

Tags: powershell, testing, scripting, chocolatey, dry-run

I'm working on a script to automate setting up new machines to a certain specification, which includes downloading a bunch of programs and changing user preferences.

I would just set a variable for the downloads and registry edits but most of the packages downloaded are through Chocolatey which appears not to have a dry-run (what-if) mode.

Is there a way to run the script in a mode that only *prints* what actions *would* be performed, so that nothing actually gets downloaded or changed while I'm testing the program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`choco` has an option to "not do anything" - this ...

```
--noop, --whatif, --what-if
NoOp / WhatIf - Don't actually do anything.
```

i have not tested it, but it *looks* like what you want.

Comment: You can find all the common parameters that you can use here: https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-reference#default-options-and-switches

Comment: @GaryEwanPark - yep! i got the above from the same `choco -h` that your link was generated from. [*grin*]